# Scraping data from HTML page and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, screen-scraping, execute

I want to scrape data from an HTML page that contains JavaScript. I read several posts that suggest using Selenium or PyQt4.QtWebKit, but maybe I have started with the wrong step and I use `requests`.

Can I execute the JavaScript that I have stored from the response with an external library like PyExecJS or Pyv8, or should I move backwards and write the code with Selenium?

This is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {"redirect_url": "",
    "site": "uk",
    "login_username": "foo",
    "login_password": "bar"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    log = "https://secure.advfn.com/login/secure"
    r = s.get("http://uk.advfn.com/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    redirect_url = soup.select_one("#redirect_url")["value"]
    site =  soup.select_one("#site")["value"]
    data["redirect_url"] = redirect_url
    p = s.post(log, data=data)
    print(p.content)
    output=s.get('https://it.advfn.com/mercati/BIT/generaliG/ordini').content
```

This is the HTML output that I got (see full page at http://pastebin.com/bwa1hWsv):

```html
<div style="width: 990px; margin: 0 auto;min-height:200px" class="Element" id="JSToolsTrades">
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var bootConfiguration = {
        appName : "trades",
        advfnURL : "http://it.advfn.com",
        rpcURL : "http://rpc.advfn.com",
        streamerURL : "wss://streamws.advfn.com",
        alternativeStreamerUrl : "ws://streamws.advfn.com:7000",
        alternativeStreamerUrlFallback : "ws://streamws.advfn.com:80",
        newsSources : "",
        locale : "it_IT",
        site : "it",
        timezone : "Europe/Paris",
        timezoneOffset : "7200",
        indices : "",
        colorSchema : {"up":"#008000","down":"#CF0000","unchanged":"#000090"},
        changeArrows : {"up":"green_up.png","no_change":"blue_dot.png","down":"red_down.png"},
        displaySymbol : "BIT%3AG",
        feedSymbol : "BIT%5EG",
        supportEmail : "support@advfn.it",
        supportPhone : "0422 1695358",
        monitorId : "",
        fixedMonitor: "0",
        monitorSettings : {"indexBreakUp":true,"orderSymbols":true,"defaultDisplay":"1"}
    };

    var s = new Session(“username”,”67913c533ce01fe2a411bd5bd2a538ab", bootConfiguration);
    Env.setSession(s);
    s.start();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You might try [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). Which is based on selenium.

Comment: You could try simulating whatever the js is doing in python

Comment: But with PhantomJS could I execute javascript inside the variable "output"? Or I need to create a new session with that Webkit?

Comment: There a limited amount I can suggest without being able to test it (which I understand). I'd favor trying selenium - much easier with tricky javascripty, sessioned websites